# Why is this RDFa throwing errors in Google Testing Tool?

Tags: rdf, breadcrumbs, rdfa

As far as I can see, my breadcrumbs are all using the same format of RDFa (I have added URL functionality to the last breadcrumb though), but the last breadcrumb URL just doesn't seem to be recognised by Google's Testing Tool.

[image: Google Structured Data Testing Tool does not recognize the "url" of the last breadcrumb item]

The Breadcrumb links are all using the same format like this

```html
<span prefix="v: http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://dev.bellavou.co.uk" rel="v:url" property="v:title">
        <i class="fa fa-home"><span class="breadcrumb_first">Home</span></i>
    </a>
</span>

<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>

<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/contact-us/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Contact Us</a>
</span>

<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>

<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/contact-us/enquiry-form/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Enquiry Form</a>
</span>

</span>
```

Why isn't Google recognising the last URL in the markup? (Or actually, why isn't it recognising the URL as a specified type?)

Comment: If you test the snippet as provided in the question with https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/, it works fine.

Comment: Hmm yeah, so why is the entire page producing errors saying it can't recognise it, if it's reading the same code?

Comment: Well, we have no chance to tell without seeing the code. Ideally you’d include a *minimal* (removing anything unnecessary) example of the code that gives this error.

Comment: There is one other thing that seems to be flagged as a warning on the testing tool, which is the first line which is currently showing as `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: `<a href="http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/contact-us/enquiry-form/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Enquiry Form</a>` is the only line that is being flagged up on the Google Testing tool (as shown in my screenshot)

Comment: This line is the same as in your example, and as this line gets tested fine without any error, the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: The URL in question is http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/contact-us/enquiry-form/. By all means, try running it and seeing for yourself if you can find anything else in https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/. But I can't find anything else in the code that would be causing this to act strangely.

Comment: Strange. It works when copy-pasting the full source (no errors/warnings), but when entering the URL and let the tool fetch it, you get the error/warnings.

Comment: I think it's to do with the RSS feeds, as just reading the notices it's giving, it actually relates to a feed URL that Yoast is outputting. I might have to look elsewhere it seems!

Comment: But if you test the code (which *includes* the `alternate` links) directly by pasting it, everything’s okay. So I’d say this is a problem of Google’s tool, not your code.

Comment: Now that is strange. Sorry, I must have missed your earlier comment about pasting it directly. I'll try and report it to Google then.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I'm struggling with this myself and found something usefull. It seems that the testing tool displays error because the href of the last/deepest breadcrumb ends with a slash `/`.

If your URL's should end with a slash or not is something I've found different answers for. Even Google themselves are in contrast of what the test tool implicates. See https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html